# Get the sum of a currency field of all related Opportunity childs and grandchilds using a flow

Tags: visual-workflow, loop, childrelationship

I just started my flow journey and I can't find a solution to my problem.

I have two different opportunity types. In type A I want to display the sum of the Amount field of all the subordinate records of type B. All levels should be taken into account. The challenge I am facing is that I may have three type A opportunities underneath each other and then the type B opportunity with the information about the amount.

My idea was to use Get Records to find all subordinate opportunities of type B (no matter to which level) and then run them through a loop.

I can do the loop for the sum of the childs' amounts, but not the grandchilds'...

This should work with a flow or am I completely on the wrong track.

Thanks for your help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: why not use roll-up-summary fields to do this automatically (or DLRS)?

Comment: The first idea was to use a roll-up, but then I need a field for every level